# Converting NodeJS byte buffer

Tags: node.js, go

I'm trying to figure out how to convert NodeJS code like this:

```
const buffer = new Buffer(24);
offset = buffer.writeUInt32BE(this.a, offset);
offset = buffer.writeUInt32BE(this.b, offset);
offset = buffer.writeUInt8(this.c, offset);
offset = buffer.writeUInt16BE(d, e); 1 : 0, offset);
buffer.writeInt8(this.f, offset);
```

to Go.

I figured I could use

```
buffer := make([]byte, 24)
buffer[0] = a
buffer[2] = b
```

but this is not working

is there a recommended way to do something like this with Go?

Comment: What does "this is not working" mean?  What isn't working? What error, or other unexpected behavior, do you observe?

Comment: Also: What is your actual goal? Are you looking to produce byte-for-byte equivalent output?

Comment: please provide the minimal reproducible example of your attempt so we try to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [binary.ByteOrder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder).

So in your case, using Big Endian, something like :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
)

func main() {
    buffer := make([]byte, 24)

    // Uint32
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(buffer, 1)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(buffer[4:], 2)

    // Uint8
    buffer[8] = 3

    // Uint16
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(buffer[9:], 4)

    // Uint8
    buffer[13] = 5
}
```